# Using one text block for headers and bodies with bullets and different fonts

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, format, textblock

I have a `ScrollViewer` with a `TextBlock` in it that I want to populate dynamically. I'd like some advice on what the best way to do this is. Here's my XAML with one sample "entry" in the `TextBlock`.

```
<ScrollViewer Background="White">
    <ScrollViewer.Resources>
        <sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">30</sys:Double>
    </ScrollViewer.Resources>
    <TextBlock FontSize="26"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Margin="25">
            <Run Text="April 14, 2017"
                        FontFamily="VAG Rounded"
                        FontWeight="Bold" /><LineBreak />
            <Run Text="• Updates galore!" /><LineBreak />
            <Run Text="-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" />
    </TextBlock>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I want just a little space between the VAG Rounded Bold header and the default font body. It doesn't look like a Run allows for margins or padding. Should I just insert an empty line with a very small font size?

I'd appreciate any feedback on the rest of it as well.

Comment: Why wont you want to have different TextBlock for that?

Comment: `<Run Text= "   "/>`

Comment: `<LineBreak/>` that will insert full blank line.

Comment: @Karolis For simplicity, I suppose. The more elements I put in there the more potential formatting issues can arise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `Panel` such as a `Grid` as the `Content` of the `ScrollViewer` you could use several `TextBlocks` with individual margins, e.g.:

```
<ScrollViewer Background="White">
        <ScrollViewer.Resources>
            <sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">30</sys:Double>
        </ScrollViewer.Resources>-->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock FontSize="26" FontFamily="VAG Rounded" FontWeight="Bold" Text="April 14, 2017" />
        <TextBlock FontSize="26" Margin="25" Grid.Row="1">
            <Run Text="• Updates galore!" />
            <LineBreak />
            <Run Text="-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" />
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```